# AngularJS and Laravel - CORS

Tags: angularjs, session, laravel, cors, laravel-5

I have got the following setup:
AngularJS for the Frontend which makes $http requests to an Laravel API.
For example at the start the mainCtrl requests if a session in Laravel exists if so he logs the user into the app.
I have tested the API with Postman and it works perfectly.

I am using Laravel 5

I send a JSON like this

```
{
      "user":"user",
      "password":"password"
}
```

and the API checks if it is a valid if so he returns an access token.
It would write the token and the userid into a laravel session.

With the rout /checkLogin it is checked if a session with a valid token exists. This works also perfectly with Postman.

Here the two functions for the login and checkLogin from the laravel backend:

```
public function login(){
       $user = User::where('email', '=', Input::get('login'))->first();
     if($user ==  null)
         $user = User::where('login', '=', Input::get('login'))->first();
         if($user != null){
             if($user->password==sha1(Input::get('password'))){
            $token = new Token;
            $token->userid = $user->id;
            $token->token=self::getGUID();
            Session::put('user_id', $user->id);
            Session::put('user_token', $token->token);
            $token->save();
                        return $token->token;
               }else
                     return "Wrong username or password";
          }else
            return "Wrong username or password";
    }

  public function checkLogin(){
      $token =null;
      if(Session::has('user_token')){
          $token = Session::get('user_token');
      }
      if($token ==  null){
          $token = Input::get('token');
      }
      if($token != null){
          $test = Token::where('token', '=', $token)->where('userid', '=', Session::get('user_id'))->first();
          return User::where('id', '=', $test->userid)->first();
      }
      return "no session";
  }
```

What I know did was to create some Angular functions to get this working for real.
When I open my site it should check if a user is logged in. Which it actually does it triggers the get function from Login.

```
example.factory('Login', function($http) {
        return {
                get : function() {
                        return $http({
                            method: 'GET',
                            url: 'http://api.example.com/checkLogin',
                            headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' }
                        });
                },

                save : function(loginData) {
                        return $http({
                                method: 'POST',
                                url: 'http://api.example.com/login',
                                headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
                                data: loginData
                        });
                }
        }

});
```

It also seems to work fine. In my console I see "no session". Which should be ok if I am not logged in.
So I now try to login. I run the save function From Login from above. With my data put together like this:

```
$scope.logmein = function () {
    loginData = {
                        'login' : $scope.login,
                        'password' : $scope.password
                };
    Login.save(loginData)
                        .success(function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                                Login.get()
                                        .success(function(getData) {
                                            console.log(getData);
                                            if(data==="no session"){
                                                $scope.loggedin=false;
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                $scope.loggedin=true;
                                            }
                                        });

                        })
                        .error(function(data) {
                                console.log(data);
                        });
                    }
```

When I hit submit I get in my console the token like expected. Everything should be fine now. In order to update my site I run the checkLogin function again. It should now give me back my session but instead it says no session. The session should be put together when I logged in.
I have tried many hours to get this fixed but many times it gave me an CORS error or when no CORS error came it just did what I just explained.

I hope someone of you can figure out why.

Comment: just a note... `headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' }` doesn't make sense for a GET request. you aren't *sending* application/json to the server, you're receiving it FROM the server.

Comment: Oh right sorry was my mistake. Sadly it did not fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' in you response headers:

```
<?php
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
?>
```

EDIT

In lavarel is possible to set up the headers in all responses in found the code below in this gist https://gist.github.com/eweap/1df3b1662a500857133a:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class CORS implements Middleware {

 /**
  * Handle an incoming request.
  *
  * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
  * @param \Closure $next
  * @return mixed
  */
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
  return $next($request)->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*')
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
 }
}
```

You will need to set up this middleware in Kernel.php

Comment: Where exactly do I need to specify it? I have got barryvdh/laravel-cors installed since I thought there might be a cors problem.

Comment: Could you please try return response()->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'); ant the end of your methods

Comment: I still have got the same problem. That I get back a token like expected but when asking what token session has got it tells me that I have no token in my session. To clarify the new token is written to my DB but when I trigger a new checkLogin request it says that I have no token in my session.

Comment: I just noticed that I only get back a token in Firefox. In Chrome it tells me "XMLHttpRequest cannot load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'...

Comment: Hi sebi55 I updated my answer, The reason you get that in Chrome is caused by the headers not set properly.

Comment: I have got a problem at the moment registering it. I have create a fild called handleCors.php in the middleware folder copied your code and then added it to the middleware array in the kernel.php like this: 'App\Http\Middleware\HandleCors' but it keeps telling me Class App\Http\Middleware\HandleCors does not exist

Comment: Sorry my fault I was an idiot. I had just to say App\Http\Middleware\CORS like your class not like the file :D

Comment: I still get a cross origin error now in firefox and in chrome. In Postman it works though

Comment: I also thought it might be a problem with nginx but adding this: add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With,Accept,Content-Type, Origin';                                                               Did not fix the problem

Comment: I tried it in chrome and he says the following: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.

Comment: Could you please check that there is no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' headers duplicated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70743/discussion-between-sebi55-and-botero).